# OR condition while passing params in google directory api query

Tags: python, google-api, google-directory-api

I am using the google directory api where in I have used the users:list method to retrieve the users.While passing the condition in query ,I want to pass multiple parameters for a key.(eg orgUnit = /ab OR /cd I have tried different possible ways but not able to achieve .

Comment: In the future remember to post your code and what you have tried.  Seeing your code may help others in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [user.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list) method a [search users](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users) allows you to use the query paramater.

if you check the documentation [operators](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users#operators)  You will notice that it does not have the ablity to use the Or with searching.

I suggest you make two calls one for each option and then sort them locally.

Comment: Thank you ..I will try that .